# How to change upload_max_filesize

Tags: php

I want to upload a file size of `64mb` on my to site I received an error because my filesize is greater than the `upload_max_filesize` in my  PHP info,

tried changing the `upload_max_filesize` in `plesk/php` settings but all the performance settings in including `upload_max_filesize` are not editable(default).

Pls is there another way I can change the value of the `upload_max_filesize` in GoDaddy plesk?

Comment: That's probably something you should be asking Godaddy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size/2184541#2184541

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/php-upload-limits-on-shared-hosting-1475

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use .htaccess file to set limits

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

Or you can write it directly in php file:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

Or you can edit your Web.config:

1. Open //web.config.
2. Set the serviceMetadata entry in the serviceBehaviors section to true. The following sample show the text after edits for the ConfigManagementDataService web service:
3. ```
      <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="ConfigManagementService">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
   </behavior>
   ```
4. Repeat the process for all the web services.
5. Restart IIS

Comment: it seems my web server uses web.confiq instead but how can I write a standard  upload_max_filesize in web.confiq?

Comment: If you're using IIS Server you can edit it by following this steps: I will make an edit to my answer.. look there

Answer (score 0):

open the PHP version in cpanel, then go to the option as shown in below
[image: click the marked option]

then u will get this page as shown below,

[image: u can change the value here]

Comment: Pls how can I locate the cpanel?

Comment: if the site belongs to you then surely the hosting provider would have a provided you with cpanel credentials.. it can be accessed like www.youdomainname.com/cpanel
or else login your godaddy account then go to your domain name then go to open cpanel option.

Comment: The site belongs to me, I tried accessing the cpanel and I go this "The requested document was not found on this server."

Comment: You should contact godaddy then

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line of code to my .user.ini file solved my problem
 file_uploads = On. post_max_size = 50. upload_max_filesize = 50M